# Datasets based on casual conversations for chatterbots

Tags: data-request, nlp, python, ai

I am building a [chatterbot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatterbot) that can answer questions related to tennis. I wish to know if there any any available datasets than can answer casual questions like "How are you", "How is the weather today" so on and so forth.

Edit 1: I am using Python and MongoDb

Answer (score 4):

**tl;dr - find and use AIML files**

---

There is an open-source chat-box project called [A.L.I.C.E.](http://www.alicebot.org/about.html)

[image]

[Link to Demo](http://sheepridge.pandorabots.com/pandora/talk?botid=b69b8d517e345aba&skin=custom_iframe)

A.L.I.C.E. uses the [AIML format](http://www.alicebot.org/aiml.html)

> AIML (Artificial Intelligence Markup Language) is an XML-compliant language that's easy to learn, and makes it possible for you to begin customizing an Alicebot or creating one from scratch within minutes.
>
> The most important units of AIML are:
>
> aiml: the tag that begins and ends an AIML document
>
> category: the tag that marks a "unit of knowledge" in an Alicebot's knowledge base
>
> pattern: used to contain a simple pattern that matches what a user may 
>   say or type to an Alicebot
>
> template: contains the response to a user input

```
<category>
<pattern>WHAT ARE YOU</pattern>
<template>
    <think><set name="topic">Me</set></think>
    I am the latest result in artificial intelligence,
    which can reproduce the capabilities of the human brain
    with greater speed and accuracy.
</template>
</category>
```

Here are links to AIML datasets : http://www.alicebot.org/downloads/sets.html

You can also probably search Github for AIML formats: https://github.com/search?q=aiml

Comment: Thanks I am using Python though
I'll check if AIML can be integrated with Python

Comment: Found python-aiml. Acts as an interpreter