# Is there any conversational dataset for creating a chat bot with deep learning

Tags: python

I am creating a chatbot in Python-3 and I was looking for conversational data set for training the bot. I want the bot to effectively answer general questions and interact with the user with casual talks.

Comment: How much data, in what form, what language? Please read [What a good request looks like](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like)

Comment: There are  currently 13 questions on the site about [conversations](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+conversation). Possible duplicate of [Datasets based on casual conversations for chatterbots](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7167/datasets-based-on-casual-conversations-for-chatterbots)